# How to click on javascript using requests_html?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I want to extract a phone number from a website and for this I have to click on a button to show the phone number. The script is:

```
<button class="kt-button kt-button--primary post-actions__get-contact" type="button"><span class="kt-text-truncate no-pointer-event">اطلاعات تماس</span></button>
```

I am trying to use requests_html library but I can't click on this block to find the phone number.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `requests` library, as the name suggests, is for requests, nothing more.

To extract the required number, see how it arrives on the page. It is very convenient to do this using DevTools.

In the screenshot below, I look at how your name is received on the page, and I see all the requests where it is contained. Do the same with the phone number, but keep in mind that it may come in a format different from what you see on the page, so try to find the phone number by part of it.

[image: DevTools]

**Note!** You can also use `selenium`, however this is a very resource intensive tool. Try to find the required request to get a phone number.

Comment: did you search my name in filter field?

Comment: @ArefFarzaneh, no, in the search box. To open it, you need to click on the "magnifying glass" near the filter field.

Comment: I did the same but unfortunately I cant see the number

Comment: @ArefFarzaneh, There are several notes: 1) DevTools must be open before loading the page (so refresh your page), 2) The number must be displayed on your screen (click on the "Contact" button), 3) The number can be in a different format (try to search piece by piece).

Comment: I found that. There is an api to get the number
here it is:
https://api.divar.ir/v5/posts/AYoo_L1J/contact/
But when I tried to extract the phone number, the response is 401

Comment: @ArefFarzaneh, Yes, that's what I said. It's easier to make a request to an API method than to use something third-party. Mark this answer as a solution to your question.

Comment: @ArefFarzaneh, add headers to your request like in browser.

Comment: Could you tell me how to make a request to this API?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228694/discussion-between-aref-farzaneh-and-dzianis-talkachou).